# Getting all the children of the associated model where condition holds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, where-clause

I have a model "Server" which has many "Categories". So 2 model: Server & Category. How do I get all the categories a server has depending on a field Category has.

Something like this: @categories_of_the_server= Server.find(params[:id]).categories.where(:check=>0)

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's wrong with that query you included in your question?

Comment: Apparently I was passing the wrong argument 'id'. Just realized it.

Comment: That's fine. Please answer your own question and accept your answer so the question won't stay unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

```
@server = Server.find(params[:id])
@categories_of_the_server = @server.categories.where("field_name = ?", value)
```

field_name is your category field and value is the value of that field

Comment: Thanks for the answer but my query was also correct. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

My query is right as well. So there was no problem with it except i was passing the wrong argument "id".